# simple Iteration on python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, methods

My aim is to write a class and use the `__iter__` and `next` methods only, to find the divisors of a number. Here is what I wrote:

```py
class Divisors(object):
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.integer = integer
    def __iter__(self):
        self.divisor = 1
        return self
    def next(self):
        div = 0
        if self.divisor >= self.integer:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            if self.integer % self.divisor == 0:
                div = self.divisor
            self.divisor += 1
        return div
```

And when I check with :

```py
for i in Divisors(6):
    print i
```

I get

```
1
2
3
0
0
```

instead of `1 2 3 6`

But I am not sure if I should use print instead of the **div** I used above. Any hint about what I did wrong here?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `Divisors` _really_ shouldn't be a class. It'd make more sense as a function.

Comment: Why is 4 a divisor of 6?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips for debugging your code.

Comment: @chrisz typo sorry about that, edited it. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, but actually the point is that I have a test tomorrow, and it will cover the class and methods, so am trying to think of simple examples I can practice with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should proceed line by line whenever debugging in situations like this. The code you have written does not print just the divisors of a number.

If you look carefully at the method `next`, it first initializes `div` to 0. Then if the divisor is greater than or equal to the integer it stops the loops. Otherwise, if the integer is divisible by the divisor it modifies `div` and then returns the `div` (either modified or original 0).

Following the above logic, your code returns 0 whenever the integer is not divisible by the divisor. And it stops as soon as the loop is executed 5 times (for integer=6). hence the output `1 2 3 0 0`. In first three iterations, the divisor divides the integer successfully (divisor = 1, 2, 3) while in next two it does not (divisor = 4 and 5). When divisor becomes equal to the integer (6 in this case) the loops stops without returning anything.

Here is the working code for python2 which produces the desired output

```
class Divisors(object):
def __init__(self,integer):
    self.integer = integer

def __iter__(self):
    self.divisor = 0
    return self

def next(self):
    div = 0

    self.divisor += 1
    while self.integer >= self.divisor and self.integer % self.divisor != 0:
        self.divisor += 1

    if self.divisor > self.integer:
        raise StopIteration

    div = self.divisor
    return div


for i in Divisors(6):
    print i
```

The output produced is:

```
1
2
3
6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I have been managed to fix it as well! Love your patience for the detailed review .

Answer (score 0):

You need a `while` loop inside your `next()` method.  We can add that and yet simplify your logic:

```
class Divisors(object):
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.integer = integer

    def __iter__(self):
        self.divisor = 1
        return self

    def next(self):

        while self.integer % self.divisor != 0:

            self.divisor += 1

            if self.divisor > self.integer:
                raise StopIteration

        self.divisor += 1

        return self.divisor - 1
```